# Drupal 7 - Views - Where has the "Empty text" functionality gone?

Tags: text, view, drupal-7

Like the question goes - I can't see "Empty text" functionallity in Views module under Drupal 7 core. There is header and footer, but empty text has gone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's in "Advanced -> No results behavior" when constructing the view

Answer (score 0):

It acts kind of differently though. If you have exposed filters then the no results behavior will hide the exposed filters, whereas with empty text that would be how to keep the exposed filters showing. For this problem I cannot find an answer.